# SharePoint 2013 Online Workflow Stage Change

Tags: workflow, events

I have the following problem with workflow status updates:

Workflow (A) is triggered On Creation of document (D).
Workflow (B) is triggered On Change of document (D).
When workflow (A) moves between workflow stages, it registered a modification against document (D), causing workflow (B) to be triggered.
I don't want workflow (A) to be modifying document (D) or triggering workflow (B).

The issue seems to be related to workflow stage names. If workflow (A) has default stage names ("Step 1", "Step 2", etc) it doesn't seem to register modify events on document (D). When the stage names are non-default, the workflow does register modifications. But I am not 100% confident that this is the cause of the problem.

Keen to learn if anyone has encountered a similar issue. I need to suppress these unnecessary status updates.